# Unity3D Terrain Generation

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've made a script that instantiates 4 sorts of 'biomes' (at the moment just colored cubes). The concept is that when the player starts a world, the script first generates the start area. To this point everything is still OK. But now I need to find a way to generate more of these cubes (with instantiate). But I think loading like 10000000 cubes is very hardware intensive, so I thought to make it so that it only generates (and loads) cubes where the player is watching. And then deload and save them when the players leaves the area. But I have no clue how to do this. If anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: i believe you want to look-up a concept called "chunking", essentially storing a bunch of terrain or other data in areas called chunks but only attempting to draw or run calculations on chunks that are relevant - one typical way of doing this only when those chunks are within a certain distance of the player.  take a look at this question for a better idea of the concept http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71942/loading-chunks-of-the-terrain-relative-to-the-players-position

Comment: do you by any chanche have any idea to to this? like a small example ? or some function that might help me? :) thank you

Comment: heres a better example of a very similar question this time in unity http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15635/how-can-i-make-huge-terrains-in-unity/15646#15646

Comment: also, another hard think, i don't wanna make another voxel, minecraft-typish game, i want to make terrain generation, but i want 'real' terrain, not block. will i need to do the same thing as with blocks when i'm gonna be generating curvy terrain?